# Adding click event dynamically is not working

Tags: c#, button, dynamic, onclick

first time questioner here.

I have CSharp code in VS2017 as below - it is placed in only the first row of a dynamic table:

```
 if(intN == 1)
 {
    tc = new TableCell();
    tc.CssClass = "FNT_14_Bold";
    btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "btnSubmitCurrentUserChanges";
    btn.Height = 25;
    btn.Width = 261;
    btn.Text = "Submit Current Users Changes";
    btn.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#006F6F");
    btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnUsers_Click);
    tc.Controls.Add(btn);
}
else
{
    tc = new TableCell();
    tc.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
    tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    tc.CssClass = "FNT_14";
}

protected void btnUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SubmitData();
}
```

When I click on the button, it fires, but only as far as the Page_Load.  Any suggestions on getting it to the actual event?

Thanks in advance... StackOverflow has been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the first part of your code is from `Page_Load`. You need to move it to `Page_Init`. That way the dynamically created controls are ready to fire the events when the page has loaded.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry I didn't explain this more fully - the first part of my code is in a procedure that creates and fills a dynamic table.  The button is created during that procedure to occur only once - on the first row.

Can I create a button in the Page_Init and then reference it in a dynamically created table?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. You should create on each Page_Init, both when you generate the html and when you want the clickhandler to execute (just set it's 'Vivible' property to false on postback).